# resize an array of pointers without memory leak

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, object

I have a pointer to an array of pointers-to-objects, and need to resize the array. I do realize this is a perfect time to use vectors, But I'm not permitted to do so. My code works, but I don't completely follow what I've written, and concerned i may have created memory leaks:

```
void foo (DataSet &add_data)
{
    if (sets == NULL)
    {
        sets = new DataSet*[1];
        sets[0] = &add_data;
    }
    else
    {
        DataSet **transfer;        
        transfer = new DataSet*[num_of_sets];       

        for (int i = 0; i < num_of_sets; i++) // Copy addresses?
            transfer[i] = sets[i];     

        delete [] sets; // Free the array.        
        sets = new DataSet*[num_of_sets + 1]; // Create new sets  

        for (int i = 0; i < num_of_sets; i++) // Copy back
            sets[i] = transfer[i];            

        sets[num_of_sets] = &add_data;        // Add the new set        
        delete [] transfer;
        transfer = NULL;
    }    
    num_of_sets++;
}
```

Why does Visual Studio throw an exception for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_of_sets; i++) // Copy addresses?
    *transfer[i] = *sets[i];
```

but not:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_of_sets; i++) // Copy addresses?
    transfer[i] = sets[i];
```

But both code segments compile and run without fault in linux. This code should copy the pointers-to-objects. Is that what is happening with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_of_sets; i++) // Copy addresses?
    transfer[i] = sets[i];
```

And do I need to be concerned if I want to free these objects with say a remove function later?

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataSet>>`.

Comment: I can't use vector... I know :(

Comment: Why can nobody use a vector these days?

Comment: @JameyD, usually it's part of a misguided assignment that aims to teach one "true" c++ by forbidding the use of the standard library.

Comment: @StoryTeller Rather C99. Same goes for everyone that keeps using raw pointers instead of smart pointers and the teachers that keep teaching to use raw ones.

Comment: Storing the address of the parameter is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: `new[]`/`delete[]` and manually copying is worse than just using `realloc`.

Comment: Indeed the code can use malloc/free/realloc as well, but beware the pitfalls of realloc (people rarely use it right, creating a possible memory leak on the spot - if realloc fails and returns null, it does not free the original memory block and I have seen people having it wrong countless of times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to allocate twice, just allocate once the final size:

```
    transfer = new DataSet*[num_of_sets + 1]; // Create new sets - final size

    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_sets; i++) // Copy addresses?
        transfer[i] = sets[i];

    delete [] sets; // Free the array.

    sets = transfer;

    sets[num_of_sets] = &add_data;        // Add the new set
    // now no need to delete[] transfer
```

That way you also get improved exception safety btw. - in your original code, you deleted the `sets` before allocating the new data to it - if that would throw `std::bad_alloc`, not only your object will become inconsistent (having a dangling `sets` ptr because you do not assign null to it after delete) but also the memory allocated to `transfer` would leak. If you allocate `transfer` directly to final size before `delete[] sets`, if that will throw, `sets` will stay intact and `transfer` will not leak (because it threw during allocation i.e. did not allocate).

Of course, make sure that you `delete[] sets` in the destructor (and maybe the pointers as well, in case your set is owning them).

Comment: Yes, I'm clear on `delete [] sets` in my destructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
*transfer[i] = *sets[i];
```

Does not copy addresses, like the other sample (without asterisks) does, it tries to dereference the uninitialized pointer elements of `transfer` and call `operator=` on `DataSet` objects on these addresses.

It's undefined behavior, that's why it appears to work under changed circumstances.

Comment: Thats what I thought... but I had doubts because both transfer and sets are pointers to a pointer array, that maybe I need to specify the value (dereference) in that array.

Comment: `[]` is one dereference, `*` is a second dereference. Since you have pointers to pointers and want to copy the pointed at pointers, you want only one dereference.

Comment: THANK YOU... that makes sense now!

Comment: @Michael By the way, Is it desired that your function only manages one array of pointers, and it knows nothing about the lifetimes of the objects these pointers point to?

Comment: Yes. If I understand you question correctly.  These objects should not be freed outside of the class that they get instantiated in.

EDIT:  Maybe i should do a NULL check... hmm...

Comment: @Michael How exactly are they instantiated?

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt *Maybe i should do a NULL check* -- That check is not going to work if you set a local pointer (that happens to have the same address as the original pointer) to NULL.  `void foo(int *x) { delete x;  x = NULL; } int main() { int *p = new int; foo(p); }`  Note that `p` still has the same address before and after `foo` is called.  Setting `x` to NULL did absolutely nothing to the original pointer.

Comment: @Michael I think that every time you're instructed to write a memory-managing class with raw pointers, you should be basically re-implementing parts of the standard library (for your own good). Never make a class that has to manage two layers of pointers. Instead, use separate instances to manage each.